# sprintf conversion lacks type at end of format

Tags: c, printf

I'm using sprintf in my C program and I'm trying to format a string.

Here is my code:

```
sprintf(string, "| %-5%lu | %-9%s | %-9%s | %c | %-4%f |", currentPtr->s.SID, currentPtr->s.lname, currentPtr->s.fname, currentPtr->s.initial, currentPtr->s.GPA);
```

And I keep getting a the warning:

```
warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat]
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Edit: I'm sorry I should add my structures so you guys know what types my variables are.

structures:

```
typedef struct student {
    char lname[ 10 ], initial, fname[ 10 ];
    unsigned long SID;
    float GPA;
} SREC;

typedef struct node {
    SREC s;
    struct node *nextPtr;
} Node;

typedef Node *NodePtr;
```

currentPtr is a NodePtr

Edit2: SOLVED THANKS GUYS! :)

Comment: `%-5%lu` --> `%-5lu`

Comment: Side note: Never use sprintf. Always use snprintf instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"| %-5%lu | %-9%s | %-9%s | %c | %-4%f |"
      ^        ^       ^            ^
```

You have extra `%` between field width and type specifier. For example, `%-9%s` is not valid format specifier. It should be `%-9s` (i.e. without extra `%` at middle).

The syntax for `printf` formatting is like this (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Syntax)):

`%[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type`

So everything except `%` and `type` are optional and no `%` in middle.

P.S: Please note that `parameter` is POSIX extension, not C standard.

Comment: noor -    Does '-'  belongs to parameter option or flags option?  Is this left justification?

Comment: @Nguaial `-` belongs to flags section.